# codeigniter app not running on heroku

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

here is my procfile

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

.gitignore

```
*/config/development
*/logs/log-*.php
!*/logs/index.html
*/cache/*
!*/cache/index.html
!*/cache/.htaccess
/nbproject/private/
/vendor/
```

index.php which is inside the application folder , I added,

```
*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

require('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

and then in vendor/autoload.php I have

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

and in my config.php in config file inside application, I have

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I have searched alot but I couldnt figure out a way on why i am getting 404 page not found in heroku. I want to know what I am doing wrong.
And also wanted to know if its something due to the database? since I only have my database on local host.

Answer (score 0):

After my research during the last few days, I noticed that very few people understand Heroku.

I think your config is unusual, index.php should in the root not in the application folder. I've tried pure flesh CodeIgniter, still not working in Heroku, someone suggested moving to AWS Elastic Beanstalk which might be a better solution.